# VBA Excel - Outlook - For Each - Returns mail = nothing - Error mngt

Tags: vba, email, foreach, error-handling, outlook

I made a small macro on Excel which aims to look for a mail on outlook with a specific subject and a specific received time. Works pretty well with almost everyone but bugs with the oulook inbox one of my colleague.

The code i wrote:

```
For Each olMail In oDefaultFolder.Items
    If olMail.Subject = "DDJ of " & date_target Then
        MyAr = Split(olMail.Body, vbCrLf)

        For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
        Sheets("DDJ").Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = MyAr(i)
        Next i
        ddj_empty = False
        Exit For
    End If
Next olMail
```

I tried with 3 outlook accounts and there was no pb but with the 4th account it bugs.. I deleted one manually but there are too many, from appointment conf to mails which seemed normal

The pb it returns is it highlights "Next oLMail" and says oLMail = Nothing
I would like for my macro to go on and continues its search and i have some trouble to handle this nothing error.

i was looking for smtg similar to "if mail = nothing then i = i+1 .. next i " but i found on google a "continue for" but my excel doesn't recognize the continue function ? so i don't know what to do

Any advice?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook folders can contain [different item types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864247.aspx).  The different types are not identical.  The [MeetingItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868714.aspx), for example, supports the [MeetingWorkspace property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868525.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  [MailItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861332.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) do not.

Before using `olMail` it is a good idea to check the type, using the vba [TypeName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5422sfdf(v=vs.90).aspx) function.

```
' Perform action on specific item types only.
' TESTED: Outlook 2010.
Sub CheckItemType()
    Dim i As Object         ' Used to loop over items.
    Dim iType As String     ' Used to hold type of above item.

        ' Loop over all items in the inbox.
        For Each i In Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
            iType = TypeName(i)

            ' Limit actions to required types.
            If iType = "MailItem" Or iType = "MeetingItem" Then
                ' Your logic.
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: SORRY!  I wrote the code using Outlook.  Just noticed your example is taken from Excel.  The TypeName and If statement are the only bits you need.  Simply add these to your existing code.

Comment: Thanks i'll try that and i'll tell you if it fixes the pb!